# Android DatePicker display Month name

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying use Date Picker and on Select i want to display the date in the following format

[Month name] [date], [year]

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-13;
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

that gives Month as a number. How to get the name of the month instead of number.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

use an array and get the String by `MONTHS[monthNumber]`.

Comment: I am baffled this is not integrated in Android by default.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

output will be `January` if Month == 1;
Or you can use this

```
  c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

Then you get `Jan`

Comment: Thank You @pajus_cz

Answer (score 3):

Use a switch statement:

```
String monthName;
switch(mMonth){
    case Calendar.JANUARY:
        monthName = "January";
        break;
    case Calendar.FEBRUARY:
        monthName = "February";
        break;
```

etc.

Comment: Yashwanth's answer is much simpler. Don't know why I didn't think of that right away...

Answer (score 2):

After getting the year, month and day, you can format your date this way:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
```

DateFormat.MEDIUM makes the date displayed as Jan 12, 1952, in example.
If you want to display the month's full name, you can use DateFormat.LONG.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
//if or swith 

if (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)==(Calendar.FEBRUARY))  {

       // Do something like

       // String Month = "FEBRUARY";  


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting the year, month and day, you can format your date this way:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
```

DateFormat.MEDIUM makes the date displayed as Jan 12, 1952, in example.
If you want to display the month's full name, you can use DateFormat.LONG.

This is the easiest way, in my opinion.