# How to display month name from DatePickerDialog - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Hi I would like to display the month name when I click in my DatePickerDialog but it's display the month number

Here is my code

```
tvDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int nYear, int nMonth, int nDay) {
                    calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
                    tvDate.setText(nDay + "/" + (nMonth+1) + "/" + nYear);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            dpd.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the date you get from `DatePickerDialog` to display the name of the month:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int nYear, int nMonth, int nDay) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy");
    calendar.set(nYear, nMonth, nDay);
    String dateString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    tvDate.setText(dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of getting month name

**Method 1**

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

use an array and get the String by MONTHS[monthNumber].
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940354/android-datepicker-display-month-name)

**Method 2**
Setting the current date in the Calendar and getting back the month like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int nYear, int nMonth, int nDay) {
             calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,nDay);
             calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,nMonth);
             calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,mYear);
             calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
             tvDate.setText(nDay + "/" + (nMonth+1) + "/" + nYear);
     }
```

In my personal opinion, I would recommend the **Method 1**